# Batch Crashes When Running Findstr Command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

After searching around I found this bit of code that I have of course changed to work with the rest of my code:

```
set /p answ=

echo.%answ%|findstr /C:":name" >nul 2>&1 && @echo %answ::name=%> Library\user1.lib & pause || echo Not found. & pause & goto chat
```

However, the batch prompt crashes when this command is ran. I made a separate file to test what was wrong but that seems to work fine and all I did was replace the variables and such:

```
SET /p _test=

:: For Above: 12345:abcabc

echo.%_test%|findstr /C:":ab" >nul 2>&1 && @echo %_test::ab=%> Library\user1.lib & pause || echo Not found. & pause
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there a different command I can use to find something in an input?

Comment: Use brackets and spaces. You can't have variables expanding into a number and not have spaces around redirection characters. Brackets tell windows how to group your commands.

Answer (score 0):

Without checking your code, I have added some essential parentheses.

```
set /p answ=

echo.%answ%|findstr /C:":name" >nul 2>&1 && (@echo %answ::name=%> Library\user1.lib & pause) || (echo Not found. & pause & goto chat)
```